# TangoWithDjango Population Script does not work as expected

Tags: django, python-2.7, populate

When I run python populate_rango.py it gives this

```
Starting Rango population script...
- Python - Page object
- Python - Page object
- Python - Page object
- Django - Page object
- Django - Page object
- Django - Page object
- Other Frameworks - Page object
- Other Frameworks - Page object
```

Why it does not read the titles correctly like this?

```
Starting Rango population script...
- Python - Official Python Tutorial
- Python - How to Think like a Computer Scientist
- Python - Learn Python in 10 Minutes
- Django - Official Django Tutorial
- Django - Django Rocks
- Django - How to Tango with Django
- Other Frameworks - Bottle
- Other Frameworks - Flask
```

So it does not work. my populate_rango.py is:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sarpedon33.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from rango.models import Category, Page


def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat('Python')

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Official Python Tutorial",
        url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
        url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
        url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

    django_cat = add_cat("Django")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Official Django Tutorial",
        url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Django Rocks",
        url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="How to Tango with Django",
        url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

    frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Bottle",
        url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Flask",
        url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

    # Print out what we have added to the user.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(name):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Rango population script..."
    populate()
```

my project folder name is sarpedon33 that is why it is like that.

Models:

```html
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):  #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
        return self.name

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Ox(models.Model):
    horn_length = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["horn_length"]
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __unicode__(self):      #For Python 2, use __str__ on Python 3
        return self.title
```

Ok I have added Page Model however this time I get AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'name'.

Here is my settings.py :

```html
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/' # You may find this is already defined as such.

STATICFILES_DIRS = (STATIC_PATH,)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Absolute path to the media directory
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '&9(_icx1*u8l0ulfa_vx1d0=oq9%*1jjw-1zl3t8b20_)5-nny'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sarpedon33.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sarpedon33.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Please show your `Page` model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the `Page` model does not have an attribute called `name`, but you are trying to access it in the `__unicode__` method. Change the method definition like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for answering my basic level questions!

Answer (score 3):

Your models most likely lack the

```
 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

functions. When printing it calls these functions, which you override in the models. Refer to 5.3. Creating Models in http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/models.html.

Comment: @sarpşık , this is the correct answer. Your `Page` model is missing the above definition.

Comment: Yes I am sorry that I could not recognize at first glance. Thanks for your patiente for my learning progress. Now there it gives another error.